# Trying to create a new Incident Action using soap api with BMCServiceDesk__IncidentHistory__c

Tags: soap-api, action

Im new to Salesforce and trying to create my first object via the api.
I can successfully query for an Incident but when i try to add an Action on to that query, i get a number of invalid field errors etc.

```
 BMCServiceDesk__IncidentHistory__c action = new BMCServiceDesk__IncidentHistory__c()
 {
      BMCServiceDesk__FKIncident__r = incidentReference,
      BMCServiceDesk__description__c = "Internal Note (Not visible in self service)",
      BMCServiceDesk__note__c = "Some note..."
      //BMCServiceDesk__actionId__c = "00011057_6"
 };
```

The problem I have is although the actionId is of type string, trying to enter some text or any id in there results in an Invalid Field exception. My question is: Is there any code examples of how to do this or is there any way to get a mandatory field list and what values are expected?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: It may be that there is a BMCServiceDesk__Action__c object and that you need to insert one of those, get its ID and then set that in the BMCServiceDesk__IncidentHistory__c.BMCServiceDesk__actionId__c field (as the foreign key). You should be able to see the objects and how they are related under Setup -> Create -> Objects in the org.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I worked on BMC Remedyforce, but if I recall correctly, `BMCServiceDesk__actionId__c` might be a lookup field.

If this is so, you need to give `BMCServiceDesk__actionId__c` the **record ID** of the `BMCServiceDesk__Action__c` you are trying to reference, and not `00011057_6` which I'm assuming is the name/title of the action record.